# What is the best practice for initializing an instance variable in a class in python?

Tags: python, class, variables, initialization

Below two variants to initialize a class instance variable. What is the best practice for initializing an instance variable in a class in python and why (maybe none of the suggested variants)?

Assumption: variant a because it might be more explicit?

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        # EITHER
        # variant a to initialize var_1
        self.var_1 = self.initialize_var_1_variant_a(parameter)
        # OR
        # variant b to initialize var_1
        self.initialize_var_1_variant_b(parameter)
        # OR something else
        # ...

    def initialize_var_1_variant_a(self, parameter):
        # complex calculations, var_1 = f(parameter)
        result_of_complex_calculations = 123
        return result_of_complex_calculations

    def initialize_var_1_variant_b(self, parameter):
        # complex calculations, var_1 = f(parameter)
        result_of_complex_calculations = 123
        self.var_1 = result_of_complex_calculations


example_instance = Example("some_parameter")
print(example_instance.var_1)
```

Comment: Which do you think is clearer?

Comment: I think variant a because it is more explicit?

Comment: I typically prefer variant1.  Except I wouldn't call it `initialize_var_1` but rather `create_xxx` based on whatever it's creating. All things being equal, instance variables should be set in the `__init__` method.  But as @khelwood points out, use variant 2 if its clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant A is the common way to do this. It is very nice to be able to see all of the class members by looking at `__init__`, instead of having to dive into the other functions (`initialize_var_1_variant_b`) to find out exactly what attributes are set.

In general, all member attributes that a class will ever have should be initialized in `__init__`.

To come at it from another angle, `initialize_var_1_variant_a` should do as little as possible. Calculating the value of `var_1` and saving it as a class attribute are two tasks that can be easily broken apart.

It also opens up the possibility of moving `initialize_var_1_variant_a` outside of the class itself, so it could be re-used by other parts of your program down the line.